# Как достать строку из локализации OS?

Tags: c#, windows, i18n

В операционной системе есть куча текста который можно локализировать. Допустим, мне нужно узнать как называется окно "Save As" в локализации на даном компьютере.

Если стоит локализация русская, то будет "Сохранить как", если украинская, то "Зберегти як", если английская то "Save As" и т.д.

Вопрос в том, как мне достать эту строку из локализации форточки :)

Comment: [Find localized Windows strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588937/2881286) и вот [Finding localized string redirection resouces in Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1320278/761205)